# How to retrieve script parameters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the batch file MyBatch.bat and I call it like:

```
MyBatch.bat -param1=abc -param2="def jkl"
```

how from MyBatch.bat can I retrieve the value of param1 (abc) and param2 (def jkl)

Comment: Take a look at [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) as well as [parameters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Note that there are no names arguments but positional ones only…

Comment: yes but i need names arguments :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal
:parmloop
if "%~1" neq "" set "%~1=%~2"&shift&shift&goto parmloop
set -
```

Comment: I do not understand how I can retrieve the value of param1 like this ?

Comment: echo %-param1% will show the value of `-param1`

Comment: @mango it's not really work because %-param1% return me a space " " at the end of the value. ie %-param1%=abc" " and I want %-param1%=abc

Comment: Works quite fine for me. How **exactly** are you seeing this phantom space? What commands are you using? For instance, `ECHO param1="%-param1%"` shows no space at the end of the value.

Comment: @mango sorry it's was a mistake my side :(